# DELETE if table exists

Tags: mariadb

I need a script MariaDB which will run on many server at once.
And sometimes the table doesn´t exist.
There is a simple way to do that without "select schema"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script:

```
DELETE IGNORE <table> WHERE Id IN (1,4,7);
```

And welcome brow.